# How can my Outlook add-in get the Attachment object the user is right-clicking in my custom menu?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, ribbonx

**I want to get currently selected embedded Attachment object when right-clicking on it in context menu and clicking on custom button.**

These are the steps I have done so far:

- Added custom Button for ContextMenuInlinePicture ribbon context menu

  ```
  <customUI ...>
      <contextMenus>
      <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuInlinePicture">
          <button id="SendInlinePictureToHbbButton"
                  label="Send to HBB"
                  onAction="OnSendInlinePictureToHbbButtonClick" />
      </contextMenu>
      </contextMenus>
  </customUI>
  ```
- By right clicking on it I am calling my function OnSendInlinePictureToHbbButtonClick:

  ```
      public void OnSendInlinePictureToHbbButtonClick(IRibbonControl control)
  {
      var msg = "OnSendMailToHbbButtonClick \n\n";
      if (control.Context is Explorer)
      {
          msg = "Context=Explorer \n";
          var explorer = control.Context as Explorer;
          if (explorer.AttachmentSelection.Count >= 1)
          {
              msg += "AttachmentSelection \n";
              msg = explorer.AttachmentSelection
                  .Cast<Attachment>()
                  .Aggregate(msg, (current, attach) => current + attach.DisplayName + "\n");
          }
          else
          {
              var selection = explorer.Selection;
              msg += "MailItemSelection \n";
              if (selection.Count == 1)
              {
                  var olItem = new OutlookItem(selection[1]);
                  msg = msg + olItem.Subject + "\n" + olItem.LastModificationTime;
              }
              else
              {
                  msg = msg + "Multiple Selection Count=" + selection.Count;
              }
          }
      }
      MessageBox.Show(msg);
  }
  ```
- When running add-in, I can see custom context menu item when right clicking embedded image/attachment.

[image]

- After clicking on that button, above method is run, but I cannot get "AttachmentSelection". Instead I get "MailItemSelection".

[image]

- **How I can get Attachment object user is right clicking**, so I can work with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted Microsoft via MSDN subscription incident resolution and they told me that this cannot be done.

Attaching MS response:

> Hello Martin,   I am from the Messaging Developer Support team and
>   have now taken ownership of this case.  I apologise for the delay, but
>   my team currently has a very high workload and this is affecting our
>   response times.   I’ve had a look at the question as described at
>   [How can my Outlook add-in get the Attachment object the user is right-clicking in my custom menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384389/how-to-get-currently-selected-item-while-clicking-on-custom-button-context-menu)
>   , and the simple answer is that it is not possible to do what you want
>   to using the Outlook Object Model.  Your code is doing what is
>   expected, as you are querying the Explorer object for its selected
>   items – and you are having the MailItem returned.  This is the
>   selected item in the Explorer object.  There are no events/properties
>   exposed by the preview pane, so it is not possible to determine which
>   object is selected there.  It would be possible to find all the inline
>   attachments of the currently selected item if that would be helpful,
>   but the functionality you are after is not available.   Please let me
>   know if you would like any further information.